# Xamarin Forms Labs GridView not showing up

Tags: asp.net, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use GridView from Forms Lab. Problem is that I'm not getting anything shown on screen. One thing to note - when i set Content = gridView or Content = mainLayout I'm getting null pointer reference exception, but i cannot find out which element is null. Here's code in view :

```
          var itemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof (MedicineBoxItemCell));
          var gridView = new GridView();
           gridView.ItemsSource = medicineBoxViewModel.MedicineBoxViewModelItems;

        gridView.ItemTemplate = itemTemplate;

        StackLayout mainLayout = new StackLayout();

        mainLayout.Children.Add(gridView);

        var scrollView = new ScrollView()
        {
            Content = mainLayout,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
        };

        Content = scrollView;
    } 
     public class MedicineBoxItemCell : ViewCell
            {
                public MedicineBoxItemCell()
                {
                    var name = new Entry()
                    {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    };
                    name.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "MedicineBoxItem.Medicine.Name");
                    View = name;
                }
            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you testing? This a very alpha version that has some problems, specially with ItemTemplate.

Try one of the demo ViewCells and see if it works for you.. and go from there.

One thing that will not work is having a layout inside a layout on the template. For example, if you are using a Grid, and inside the grid u have a stackpanel that stackpanel and it's contents will not appear , it s somethign we don't know how to fix yet.

Comment: I'm testing in on Android.
Even when i try that grid cell is type of TextCell it is not working.
Base problem is, that i cannot add gridView to content of Page.
Content = gridView throw null point exception

Comment: It's not implemented in android yet.. having problems using templates..

We need help in there so feel free to contribute with your input on :

https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs